# How can I define third type boundary condition in ANSYS Mechanical APDL?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I'm currently working on the thermal analysis of a pipe, but i do not know how to define a third type boundary condition on the inner surface.

```
finish
/out
/CLEAR,ALL

/PNUM,KP,1  
/PNUM,LINE,1
/PNUM,AREA,1

/PREP7
!Constants used in the simulation
a=0.05
b=0.2
!third type boundary condition is used on the inner surface
Tb=30
qb=260
p0=3.1e5
!second type boundary condtion on the outer surface
hk=120
Tk=15
qk=490
hb=10
rho=7600
E=210e9
nu=0.3
alpha=1.2e-5
k=45
Tinf=20
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ET,1,PLANE77
!Material props
TOFFST,273
MPTEMP,1,Tinf
MP,EX,1,E
MP,REFT,1,Tinf
MP,PRXY,1,nu
MP,KXX,1,k

!!!!!!
K,1,0,0
K,2,a,0
K,3,b,0
K,4,0,a
K,5,0,b
LARC,2,4,1,a
LARC,3,5,1,b
L,4,5
L,2,3
AL,1,2,3,4

Lsel,s,LINE,,1,2
LESIZE,ALL,,,50
LSEL,inve
LESIZE,ALL,,,30
mshkey,1
AMesh,all
/solu
lsel,all
SFL,3,HFLUX,0
SFL,4,HFLUX,0
SFL,2,HFLUX,490
```

The problem is that i do not know how to apply convection boundary condition on the inner surface, where the inner radius is a and the temperature of the fluid is Tb.
Thanks for your help in advance.
yours sincerly,
David